# What does letter D represent in floating-point data

Tags: floating-point

I have attached two pictures below in which I am stuck on one thing which is letter  D. In floating-point why letter D is used? Letter E represents exponent but what letter D represents?

[image]

Please tell me the use of D
Thanks

Comment: What book or tesr is this taken from? What's the context? Is it for a specific programming language?

Comment: No, it's a course book for Class 9 students for computer science. Not for specific langugae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It represents the precision of the data. Usually D means double precision

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: 6.67D-11 means 6.67*10^(-11), but in double precision. It works the same way as E, but E usually is for single precision (4 bytes), and D is for double precision (8 bytes). At least it works that way in FORTRAN

Comment: @SidraM note that this is programming language specific, thus my question in my other comment. It's not a universal syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since single is 4-bytes and double is 8-bytes, the precision of each is such:

```
SINGLE  2.802597E-45 to 3.402823E+38
DOUBLE  4.490656458412465D-324 to 1.797693134862310D+308
```

QB64 also has a 32-byte variable which is:

```
_FLOAT  1.18E-4932 to 1.18E+4932
```

Comment: An interesting topic on **double precision** is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: An interesting topic on **single-precision** is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert a single precision string to the original value:

```
REM Convert 4-byte IEEE string to single variable
S! = -3.1415
S$ = MKS$(S!)
Byte0 = ASC(MID$(S$, 1, 1))
Byte1 = ASC(MID$(S$, 2, 1))
Byte2 = ASC(MID$(S$, 3, 1))
Byte3 = ASC(MID$(S$, 4, 1))
Exponent = Byte3 AND &H7F
Exponent = Exponent * 2 + Byte2 \ 128 - &H7F
Mantissa! = Byte2 AND &H7F
Mantissa! = Mantissa! * &H10000 + Byte1 * &H100 + Byte0
Mantissa! = 1 + Mantissa! / (&H1000000 / 2)
Mantissa! = Mantissa! * 2 ^ Exponent
IF (Byte3 AND &H80) = &H80 THEN
    Mantissa! = -Mantissa!
END IF
PRINT Mantissa!
END
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... did you intend to edit this into your other answer?

Comment: Yes, I split it into two answers because one is slightly off-topic but is relevant to parsing single-precision values.